# executing Jmeter on a Unix box

Tags: shell, unix, jmeter

Hello I'm working with Jmeter 2.4 and extended it creating a jmeter components jar, placed within the ext subfolder of libs. I've also created some test plans jmx files. These all run find locally. I've placed the whole jmeter directory on my Unix box, created a shell script to start it which consists of one line.

```
java JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m" jmeter -t Block1Thread-1000.jmx
```

I have also tried

```
java JVM_ARGS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m" jmeter -t Block1Thread-1000.jmx
```

But both return

```
script.sh:  line 32: java: command not found
```

My Unix is rather 101 so I'm could be missing something silly.

Cheers

Comment: Do you have java actually installed? What does `which java` say?

Comment: I do I already have a few Java apps running on the machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure java is properly installed, and that you have JAVA_HOME and a path to the java bin directory set in your user profile.

Next, the JVM_ARGS need to be set as an environment variable. This means that the command you're trying to execute need to be two commands, the first being

```
export JVM_ARGS="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
```

And the second probably just being

```
./jmeter.sh -t Block1Thread-1000.jmx
```

Please note that the second command may fail, and Linux will tell you that the script is not executable. You can change that by doing:

```
chmod +x *.sh jmeter jmeter-server
```

In the /bin directory of your jmeter installation.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like java is not added in the `PATH` environment variable of the machine you're executing the command on.

Check on the command line with `echo $PATH`?